# SSAS One data source in different cubes

Tags: security, ssas, roles, cube

I have a  big cube and i want to know if it is possible to create subcubes with the same structure but with different data, for example:

Cube Company

- Sub-Cube Office A
- Sub-Cube Office B
- Sub-Cube Office C

I can create a project for every cube, but if there is a change i have to do it in every Project and thats could take a long way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

One option I would recommend would be having your SQL tables in a database called DW. Then create a separate database called DW_OfficeA that is nothing but views over the DW tables and that have the same names as the tables in DW but only return the right set of rows for Office A. Do the same for Office B and C creating separate databases for each. You might add one helper table in each database and populate with the office identifier for that database so that all your SQL views can be identical across databases and just join to the helper table.

Now you should be able to deploy your SSAS source code to three different SSAS databases. Then change the SSAS data source connection string to point to the office specific SQL database then process it. That should let you accomplish your stated goal without maintaining 3 sets of SSAS source code.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your advice, but i thing is the same trouble but now on the Datawarehouse source.

Comment: @NestorArellano If you make each view join to the helper table you have one set of SQL view code and you deploy the views to 3 databases. Doesn't seem like a lot of work and can be scripted easily. What am I missing?